# symfony plugin installation failing [bhLDAPAuthPlugin]

Tags: symfony1, ldap, symfony-1.4, propel, symfony-plugins

I'm working on a symfony project and I need a user access conected to an LDAP server. So I searched for something already done to add to my app and found this [plugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/bhLDAPAuthPlugin) that has all I wanted.

So I tried to install with the command `$ php symfony plugin:install bhLDAPAuthPlugin`
for some reason it throws me this error:

> No release avaiable for plugin "bhLDAPAuthPlugin"

I don't really understand what that message means. I've checked the spell of the command (also copied the command given in the [page](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/bhLDAPAuthPlugin) of the plugin) and same error appears. If I had no all requeriments for instalation, other errors would be thrown, right?

PS: If you know some easy way to implement by myself the comunication with LDAP (Microsoft Active Directory) will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No exactly sure how to solve the error message, perhaps it helps is specifically specify which version you wish to install.

Otherwise there's an easy workaround:
Just download the tgz file from here:
http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/bhLDAPAuthPlugin/6_0_0

and do

```
php symfony plugin:install bhLDAPAuthPlugin-etc-etc.tgz
```